# How do you edit a many to many field in Django during save?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I currently have a model that looks like this

```
class Sector():
    featured_companies = models.ManyToManyField('Company', related_name='sectors')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sector, self).save(**kwargs)
        for company in self.featured_companies.all():
            company.is_active = True
            company.save()
```

I know that this doesn't work because of the way Django works on save. I read in another post that adding something like this to the admin should work:

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.featured_companies:
            form.cleaned_data['featured_companies'] = obj.featured_companies.all()
        super(SectorAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

However, it is still not working. How would I accomplish editing the many to many field during the save process?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [**`save_related(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) of your `ModelAdmin` and set the `is_active` field to `True` with a single query:

```
class SectorAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    # …

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        form.instance.featured_companies.all().update(
            is_active=True
        )
```

Comment: Awesome that work! Do I still need the save method for the model?

Comment: @bballboy8: no, normally that is not necessary.